# SQL Query get common column with diff values in other columns

Tags: sql, join, group-by, multiple-columns, sql-query-store

I am not very fluent with SQL.. Im just facing a little issue in making the best and efficient sql query. I have a table with a composite key of column A and B as shown below

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |

So what I need is to find rows where column C has both values of 4 and 5 (4 and 5 are just examples) for a particular value of column A. So 4 and 5 are present for two A values (1 and 2). For A value 3, 4 is present but 5 is not, hence we cannot take it.

My explanation is so confusing. I hope you get it.

After this, I need to find only those where B value for 4 (First Number) is less than B value for 5 (Second Number). In this case, for  A=1, Row 1 (A-1, B-1,C-4) has B value lesser than Row 2 (A-1, B-2, C-5) So we take this row. For A = 2, Row 1(A-2,B-2,C-4) has B value greater than Row 2 (A-2,B-1,C-5) hence we cannot take it.

I Hope someone gets it and helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows containing both `c=4` and `c=5` for a given `a` and ordered by `b` and by `c` the same way.

```
select a, b, c
from (
    select tbl.*, 
       count(*) over(partition by a) cnt,
       row_number() over (partition by a order by b) brn,
       row_number() over (partition by a order by c) crn
    from tbl
    where c in (4, 5)
) t
where cnt = 2 and brn = crn;
```

**EDIT**

If an order if parameters matters, the position of the parameter must be set explicitly. Comparing `b` ordering to explicit parameter position

```
with params(val, pos) as (
    select 4,2 union all
    select 5,1
)
select a, b, c
from (
    select tbl.*, 
       count(*) over(partition by a) cnt,
       row_number() over (partition by a order by b) brn,
       p.pos
    from tbl 
    join params p on tbl.c = p.val
) t
where cnt = (select count(*) from params) and brn = pos;
```

Comment: Thanks. This query is almost there. I get the following two rows a=1, b=1, c=4 and a=1, b=2, c=5

But when i change where c in (5,4), result rows are the same when they should be  a=2, b=2, c=4 and a=2, b=1, c=5

Comment: Do you mean ordering of parameters is important , so (5,4) is not the same as (4, 5) ?

Comment: Yes.. If it can't be done.. I just kept two queries one the above when first no<second no

When second no<first no. is just sorted in desc order

row_number() over (partition by a order by b desc) brn,

Don't know if there's a better way

Comment: Great, you're a Pro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the values of `a` where this is true.  If so, you can use aggregation:

```
select a
from t
where c in (4, 5)
group by a
having count(distinct c) = 2;
```